# Linq To Sql 'Where Or' operator

Tags: linq-to-sql, where-clause

I need to create a query which checks if a field (string) contains one or more words supplied at run time.

Basically I need to be able to ask a WhereOr question.  This seems like it should be a common issue when dealing with LinqToSql.

I found the following [reference](http://refactormycode.com/codes/1097-generic-linq-where-clause-oring-together-many) but can't make sense out of it - and have no idea how to use it in my project.

i've tried the following loop:

```
        var query = from d in context.Domains select d;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            query = query.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(words[i]));
        }
```

but this builds a SQL query with *WHERE AND* Clauses NOT *Where OR*

Comment: found an interesting resource:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: lookd like you  have found it yourself ^^ I started writing before you  posted that comment. Hope I could help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) for such things.

The predicate construction looks like this:

```
     var query = from d in context.Domains select d;
     var predicate = PredicateBuilder<Domains>.False();

     for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(d => d.Name.Contains(words[i]));
        }
    query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: Wonder why this wasn't backed into LinqToSql