# Multiple 'Or' statements in EF expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, odac

*Given a list of filter parameters in the form of:*

```
public class filterParm
{
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

*Where:*

```
var parms = new List<filterParm>
{
    new filterParm {age = 22, "phil"},
    new filterParm {age = 19, "dave"},
    new filterParm {age = 31, "nick"}
};
```

*How do I write an expression which would result in the following SQL where clause (note the **OR** operators in bold:*

WHERE (age = 22 AND name = "phil")
**OR** (age = 19 AND name = "dave")
**OR** (age = 31 AND name = "nick")

*My current implementation results in each of the statements seperated by the **AND** operator:*

```
private _dbSet<user> Users { get; set; }
public List<user> CustomFilter(List<filterParm> parms)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

    if (parms.Count > 0 )
    {
        foreach (var parm in parms)
        {                    
           query = query.Where(u => u.Age == parm.Age && u.Name == parm.Name);
        }
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

*The code above results in the following SQL:*

> WHERE (age = 22 AND name = "phil")      **AND** (age = 19
>   AND name = "dave") **AND** (age = 31 AND name = "nick")

*What do I need to change in the expression to cause the generated SQL to use 'OR' instead of 'AND' in the indicated locations?  I would prefer to avoid using third party libraries where possible.*

EDIT:
As suggested by @KingKing, a `union` does return the required results:

```
private _dbSet<user> Users { get; set; }
public List<user> CustomFilter(List<filterParm> parms)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

    if (parms.Count > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(u => u.Age == parms[0].Age && u.Name == parms[0].Name);

        for (int i = 1; i < parms.Count; i++)
        {
            var parm = parms[i];
            query = query.Union(DbSet.Where(u => u.Age == parm.Age && u.Name == parm.Name));
        }                                                   
    }
    return query.ToList();
}
```

*I would still like to know if it is possible to generate the statement using the 'Or' operator as described.*

Comment: You better have a look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775050/linq-to-sql-where-or-operator

Comment: @jyparask It looks like [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) & the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) would work for me. However, I would still be interested in knowing how to implement a solution without using a third party library if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `Union` will help:

```
public List<user> CustomFilter(List<filterParm> parms) {
  IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
  if (parms.Count > 0 ){
    IQueryable<TEntity> init = _dbSet;
    var firstParm = parms[0];
    query = query.Where(u => u.Age == firstParm.Age && u.Name == firstParm.Name);
    for(int i = 1; i < parms.Count; i++)
    {                    
       var nextParm = parms[i];
       init = init.Where(u => u.Age == nextParm.Age && u.Name == nextParm.Name);
       query = query.Union(init);
    }
  }
  return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: The second one can't be converted to EF. It's not possible to use a reference type in a contains :(

Comment: @WouterdeKort thank you, looks like that `EF` has many limitations :(

Comment: @KingKing `Concat` has generated SQL with AND operators instead of OR operators, plus it has generated a very complex statement with many bind variables. Either this isn't suitable, or I'm doing it wrong...probably the latter.

Comment: @philreed I don't know if the `translated SQL` uses `OR` or `AND` but the result should be the same when using `OR`.

Comment: @philreed I updated with `Union` instead, it should be better choice.

Comment: @KingKing `Union` would work because it would remove the requirement of the 'OR' operator but I think your example needs changing a little more for it to work. I'm testing now.

Comment: @KingKing I have amended the question to include a variant on the code you provided in your example.  Using `union` does return the correct results.  If no-one can provide an example which renders SQL using the 'OR' operator in the next couple of days, I will accept your answer.